# Android Deep link going to PlayStore instead of my app on some devices

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I've registered the following intent filter in my app's manifest:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="m.mycompany.de"
            android:pathPattern="/app/list"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
```

And created a simple html page to test if the app opens correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>
         A Small Hello 
      </TITLE>
   </HEAD>
<BODY>
   <a href = "http://m.mycompany.de/app/list?param1=178&param2=87294">Click</a>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

On some devices (e.g. Nexus 5 running Android 5.1) clicking the link opens my app as expected, on other devices (e.g. Nexus 6 also running 5.1) the PlayStore (my app's page) is opened instead of my app.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

**EDIT:** Strangely, this 'bug' is gone when simplifying the URL to :

```
http://m.mycompany.de/list?param1=178&param2=87294
```

and my intent filter to

```
   <data
        android:host="m.mycompany.de"
        android:pathPattern="/app"
        android:scheme="http" />
```

which is not an option though because I don't have control over the URLs for my live app.

Comment: When you say 'the PlayStore (my app's page) is opened instead of my app' you mean that your website is opened instead of your app or you really mean the PlayStore app?

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli There's the usual dialog asking if the link is to be opened with the Play Store App or with a browser.

Comment: The 'm.mycompany.de' inside the manifest and 'm.mycompany' inside the link and inside the html page is a typo, right? You always mean 'm.mycompany.de'?

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli Oh yeah, that was a typo. Edited my question, thanks.

Comment: What I don't understand is: you have http as scheme; the http scheme is managed by browsers and by your app. So it's normal that the user will be prompted to choose the app that will have to handle the link (browser or your app). Actually you say that some devices offer to open the link with the browser or with Play Store: have you tried to clear the data of play store app (it's safe)?

Comment: Any comment? Can you answer my questions or have you fixed the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to replace `android:pathPattern` with `android:pathPrefix`?

Comment: I would recommend checking out Branch.io. It makes deeplinking a lot easier.

Comment: can you please  display the piece of code of the activity where you handle the get intent

Comment: Hey guys thanks for all your comments. Miracoluosly  the problem vanished into thin air, my app responds to the the links I posted as desired, I haven't changed anything in the code. 
Perhaps something went wrong on the build process, I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **pathprefix** instead of **android:pathPattern**

```
<data 
      android:host="m.mycompany.de"
      android:pathPrefix="/app/list"
      android:scheme="http" />
```

and in second case when you use below url,

http://m.mycompany.de/list?param1=178&param2=87294

the data tag should be

```
<data 
      android:host="m.mycompany.de"
      android:pathPrefix="/list"
      android:scheme="http" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you use data section's pathPattern parameter in wrong direction.

According to Google [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html):

> The pathPattern attribute specifies a complete path that is matched
>   against the complete path in the Intent object.

So you need to use pathPrefix instead of pathPattern:

> The pathPrefix attribute specifies a partial path that is matched
>   against only the initial part of the path in the Intent object.

Or just discard path and use only host and scheme like that:

```
<data
    android:host="m.mycompany.de"
    android:scheme="http" />
```

P.S. Additionally note Mimmo Grottoli comment for original message.